# Unable to display $scope in view

Tags: angularjs

I am querying a database and retrieving all the images belonging to the logged-in user, here is that code in uploadController:

```
UserImage.get($scope.user_id)
   .success(function(data) {

       $scope.userArray = data;

       $location.path('/display');
    });
```

I can console log the value of data and it is (first document):

```
0: Object
__v: 0
_id: "563bd07c7a49a7ac9ae1c513"
date: "2015-11-05T21:56:12.312Z"
gallery: "first gallery"
name: "1b0f6d56-9ed6-4412-a0d6-897a25fb3a84-460x360.jpeg"
user: "563bd0527a49a7ac9ae1c512"
```

so now I test that the target view (display.html) can receive the $scope.data:

```
<<div>{{userArray[0].name}}</div>
```

The $scope.userArray is not available to the display.html.
 I tested the $scope in plunker and it worked ok:
http://plnkr.co/edit/q5XXnfl3JxkRdG0jLyps?p=preview
So I am a bit stumped.

Comment: You have not included your routing but it appears you add data to your scope then change the path, I assume to a new route with a different scope?

Comment: @Tristan - actually the same controller - no change. I tried swapping it so the path changed before the $scope was given the data but no difference.

Comment: @Sajeetharan the error is that the data in $scope.userArray is not available to the display.html code.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you should use ".then" instead of ".success" to use to promise system. [If you want to know more about it](http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/25/dont-use-$https-success/)

And i think your problem is also connected with `$location.path('/display');` you ask your application to change location as soon as you get the answer, so it is probably loading another controller and stopping with your current one.

Comment: yes I  forgot about success and error being deprecated. As I was already getting the right data in $scope.userArray, I think you're right the $location.path is messing things up. I use the same controller for the display view but can you suggest an alternative to the $location.path. thanks